# GraphAPI - can't get calendar events for any other user except myself

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I don't understand the problem. My user is the administrator of a test Azure directory and I have dummy users that were setup automatically. I can get calendar events for myself using my email just fine:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/iamtheadmin@w8tlt.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events
```

but whenever I try to retrieve calendar events from any other dummy user (by just switching the email address in GraphAPI request URL), I get the following error in Graph Explorer:

```
"code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
"message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
```

The dummy users I'm trying to retrieve events for have multiple events in their calendars so empty calendar is definitely not an issue.

I have set up my permissions in Azure AD/App registrations/API permissions:

[image]

I can't figure out what detail/setting/permission I'm missing.

Comment: Did you assign any license (plans) to dummy users in Azure Portal? Does /v1.0/users/{dummy_user_id} return user's info?

Comment: @user2250152 yes, /v1.0/users/{dummy_user_id} returns info for any user I want to. Can you expand on what you mean by assigning license to user? Where can I set this?

Comment: In Azure Portal when you click on Users -> Your dummy user -> Licenses. There is a list of products and enabled services.

Comment: As @sridevi mentioned in the answer, when you are using Graph Explorer you need Delegated permissions not Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran the same query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I can get calendar events for myself using my email like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myaccount@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

But when I tried to retrieve calendar events of other user, I got **same error** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/otheruser@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

The error occured as Graph Explorer uses **Delegated** permissions but retrieving other user calendar events require **Application** permissions.

> As you already assigned **`Application`** permissions in your application, just generate an access token using **client credentials** flow and use it to run Graph queries.

In my case, I used Postman to generate **access token** with *client credentials* flow like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to run below graph query, I got calendar events of **other user** successfully like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/otheruser@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendar/events
```

**Response:**

[image]